# Can I release code that modifies a Java class

Tags: java, licensing

I've read through the Java license agreement, but it confuses me greatly (as do most licenses).

Here is what I want to do

1. Take one of the existing Java classes and modify it very slightly. (not enough that I could consider it my own novel work)
2. Put that modified class in a publicly available spot (in this case Github)

Under the Java license and terms, can I do this?

[Java License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask a lawyer ?

Comment: Sure, if you tell me a lawyer to answer questions for free. Also this is something I obviously don't need to do, I don't need to release it to the public, I just would like to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenJDK is opensource under [GPLv2 with the classpath exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html) so go ahead. You can [clone their Mercurial repository](http://openjdk.java.net/guide/repositories.html) and under the license can publish changes to your own public repository.

Answer (score 1):

From point 2:

> Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license
>   without license fees to reproduce and use internally the Software
>   complete and unmodified for the sole purpose of running Programs.

And point 3:

> RESTRICTIONS. Software is copyrighted. Title to Software and all
>   associated intellectual property rights is retained by Oracle and/or
>   its licensors. Unless enforcement is prohibited by applicable law, you
>   may not modify, decompile, or reverse engineer Software.

There you go. That should solve the question ;)

You can however create a class that uses and changes attributes from a base java class. That way you'll act under their lisence, because you can use it to create whatever you want.

Comment: Ugh, I really just wanted to take a class that uses an Enum, and make it use an Integer. Guess I'll have to make my own that does essentially the same thing...

Comment: So what I gather from that is, find a micronation, ask them to make a law "prohibiting enforcement", and post it on a server running there. ;)